# Play audio on specific time from database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I’m building a audioplayer based on Howler.js that plays audio on specific time without refreshing.
The plan is to make a small CMS system where I can make the schedule including the audio file.

The challenging part: How can I read my database (MySQL) realtime checking if it’s time to play?
it's working by checking the database every second (And reloading the page), but I think it’s not a solution. ;-)

Is there someone with a brilliant advice?

Comment: Can the date change after inserting the record into the database? an possible solution would be to fetch the date once, calculate the time left on the client and use `setTimeout` to call the code after the calculated time.

Comment: It won’t change. I’ll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onended

```
let sound=new Audio('sound.mp3');
sound.play(); // play sound

sound.onended=function (){

   alert('sound the end');

}
```